Use CMake to link to objects created by an executable project
I have a CMake based project that builds several applications and libraries
Now I need to perform some unit testing. My unit test project will need to access the objects produced by the building of the applications.
To attempt to achieve this I have added this to the CMakeLists file for one of the apps
add_library(HQTestObjects OBJECT AutoMode/BusinessLogic/FileDetector.cpp)

Then I use it in the unit test project
target_link_libraries(HQTests

Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core
Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Test
HQTestObjects)

Unfortunately, this results in compilation errors of the form:
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QDir': No such file or directory

Screenshot:


On Stack Overflow we expect both code and error message to be in the question post as text, not linked as image. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit your question post accordingly. See also that question on meta.

You are likely linking to the wrong libraries. You should model your build like so:
# First, declare that the test objects depend on Qt and that
# downstreams need to link to Qt, too.
target_link_libraries(
  HQTestObjects
  PUBLIC
  Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core
  Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Test
)

# Later, link the HQTests executable to the test objects
target_link_libraries(HQTests PRIVATE HQTestObjects)

Exactly where each test should go depends on your source files' and headers requirements.
